# Java derived subclass object can't resolve symbol

Tags: java, inheritance, intellij-idea, multiple-inheritance

I am trying a `Java` inheritance code as follows.

```
class A4 {
int i, j;

A4(int a, int b) {
    i = a;
    j = b;
}

// display i and j
void show() {
    System.out.println("i and j: " + i + " " + j);
}
}

class B4 extends A4 {
int k;

B4(int a, int b, int c) {
    super(a, b);
    k = c;
}

// overload show
void show(String msg) {
    System.out.println(msg + k);
}
}

class Overload {
B4 subOb = new B4(1, 2, 3);

subOb.show("This is k: "); // this calls show() in B4, also cannot resolve symbol 'show`
subOb.show(); // this calls show() in A4, also cannot resolve symbol `show`
}
```

the problem is that `subOb` can not be resolved, as the IDE (`IntelliJ`) caught two errors shown in the code. I am wondering what is wrong with the code and how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Put those inside a method.

Comment: What packages are the classes in? All in the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the wrong scope.

Methods have to be called within other methods or to initialize fields.

You could do something like this:

```
class Overload {
    static B4 subOb = new B4(1, 2, 3);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        subOb.show("This is k: "); // this calls show() in B4, also cannot resolve symbol 'show`
        subOb.show(); // this calls show() in A4, also cannot resolve symbol `show`
    }
}
```

or this:

```
class Overload {
    B4 subOb = new B4(1, 2, 3);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Overload obj = new Overload();
        obj.doStuff();
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        subOb.show("This is k: "); // this calls show() in B4, also cannot resolve symbol 'show`
        subOb.show();              // this calls show() in A4, also cannot resolve symbol `show`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the call inside a method:
Try this:

```
class Overload {
  B4 subOb = new B4(1, 2, 3);

  void overLoad(){
      subOb.show("This is k: ");
      subOb.show();
  }
}
```